# Lazy Loading, Collections and Single or First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have the following model:

A User has a collection of Photos.  In the Photo model, there is a property called IsProfilePhoto.

When I do the following, the results are not as expected.

```
var user = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);
var profilePhoto = user.Photos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.IsProfilePhoto);
```

With lazy loading on, this performs two queries.

The first one gets the user by id as expected.
The second one however, gets the collection of photos by user id and then in memory does the match on IsProfilePhoto.

I was hoping that with lazy loading on it would add the SingleOrDefault to the query as well.

Is this just not possible and I must always do the inverse?  E.g.

```
var profilePhoto = dbContext.Photos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserId == 1 && p.IsProfilePhoto);
var user = profilePhoto.User;
```

I get the reasoning, there are just certain reasons why it's more convenient to go from the User to get the profile photo.

Comment: You have to use Eagerly loading to load multiple levels. Lazy load, loads the level when you access this.

Comment: If you're concerned about the multiple queries, you could use .Include to include the photos in one call - `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx`

Comment: @RickDailey I'm not concerned about the multiple queries, just about the inefficency of not doing the IsProfilePhoto on the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result with a single database query by using a projection:

```
var userWithProfilePhoto = dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == 1)
    .Select(u => new
    {
        User = u,
        ProfilePhoto = u.Photos.Where(p => p.IsProfilePhoto).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

`userWithProfilePhoto.User` and `userWithProfilePhoto.ProfilePhoto` are the two entities you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting solution. According to the metrics though, this isn't as efficient starting at the photos table and going up to the user because it still does a sub select.  It does however correctly do the filtering at the DB.

Comment: @endyourif: With SQL Server I wouldn't consider the sub selects as a problem because the database engine will still generate an efficient query plan. Almost all non-trivial LINQ queries are translated to a SQL that contains sub selects. You literally can't use LINQ-to-Entities if that is disturbing you. Also keep in mind that your solution to start from the photos and then fetch the user will cost *two* database queries (because the user is lazily loaded) instead of only one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Eagerly loading to load multiple levels. Lazy load, loads the level when you access this.

```
var user = dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Photos).SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1);
var profilePhoto = user.Photos.SingleOrDefault(p => p.IsProfilePhoto);
```

Comment: That is far less efficient because including the collection EF does crazy sub selects.

Answer (score 1):

This is the subtle difference in LINQ methods.

You can do the filtering as part of the query as:

```cs
var profilePhoto = user.Photos.Where(p => p.IsProfilePhoto).SingleOrDefault();
```

Due to this behavior in LINQ to Entities, I try to always use the `Where` method for the condition and the parameterless overloads for `First`, `Single`, `FirstOrDefault`, `SingleOrDefault`, `Any`, and `Count`.

Edit:

My bad, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) mentions it directly, but any reference to a navigation property (when lazy loading is enabled) loads all of the related records.

My best suggestion then is to a) accept extra database access, or b) query as you did in your alternative example, with the first table being the 'many' of the 'one-to-many' relationship.

Comment: Putting the condition in the where had no affect on making the query to the database add the IsProfilePhoto to the where claus.

Comment: Ah, you're right about navigation properties -- there is no way for conditional lazy loading [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272(v=vs.100).aspx). Unfortunately, you have to write precise single queries for efficient SQL generation. ORMs generally aren't as efficient as manually tuned SQL.

Comment: Yep I know.  The solution that gets me the right query is the 2nd one where I select from Photos first and include user, but as I said it's not always easy to start at the collection and work your way up.

Comment: Entity Framework query tuning is definitely an art. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, and FirstOrDefault are lazy loaded, Single, and SingleOrDefault eagerly loaded. If you don't need a an exception thrown in case of several items returned by the query, you can change it to FirstOrDefault.